# Vue store and computed doesnot reactive even with vue set

Tags: vue.js, vuex, reactive, computed-properties

I have following computed property in my Vue component:

```
  computed: {
    contragent_id: {
      get() {
        return appData.getters["basket/contragent_id"];
      },
      set(value) {
        return value;
      },
    },
    settings: {
      get() {
        return appData.getters["basket/delivery_settings"];
      },
      set(value) {
        return value;
      },
    },

    presets: {
      get() {
        return appData.getters["basket/delivery_presets"];
      },
      set(value) {
        return value;
      },
    },
  },
```

And i have the Vuex store module :

```
const moduleBasket = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: () => ({
    presets: {
      contragents: [],
      partners: {},
      delivery: {
        types: {},
        methods: {},
        tc_methods: {},
        tc_list: {},
        addresses: [],
      },
    },
    summary: {
      delivery: {
        delivery_type: "",
        delivery_method: "",
        delivery_tc: "",
        delivery_tc_method: "",
        delivery_tc_city: "",
        delivery_address_id: "",
      },
      payment: {
        method: "",
        methodText: "",
      },
      address: {},
      comment: "",
      partner_id: "",
      contragent_id: "",
      price: {
        total: "",
        nds: "",
        delivery: "",
        discount: "",
      },
      fillial: {
        address: "",
      },
    },
  }),
  mutations: {
    changeFillial(state, fillial) {
      Vue.set(state.summary, "fillial", fillial);
    },
    changePartnerId(state, partner_id) {
      Vue.set(state.summary, "partner_id", partner_id);
    },
    changeContragentId(state, contragent_id) {
      Vue.set(state.summary, "contragent_id", contragent_id);
      // state.summary.contragent_id = contragent_id;
    },
    changeContragents(state, contragnets) {
      Vue.set(state.presets, "contragents", contragnets);
      // state.presets.contragents = contragnets;
    },
    changePartners(state, partners) {
      Vue.set(state.presets, "partners", partners);
      // state.presets.partners = partners;
    },

    changeDeliveryPresets(state, presets) {
      // console.log('changeDeliveryPresets');
      Vue.set(state.presets, "delivery", presets);
      // state.presets.delivery = presets;
    },
    changeDeliveryPresets__types(state, types) {
      // console.log('changeDeliveryPresets__types');
      Vue.set(state.presets.delivery, "types", types);
      // state.presets.delivery.types = types;
    },
    changeDeliveryPresets__methods(state, methods) {
      Vue.set(state.presets.delivery, "methods", methods);
      // state.presets.delivery.methods = methods;
    },
    changeDeliveryPresets__tc_methods(state, tc_methods) {
      Vue.set(state.presets.delivery, "tc_methods", tc_methods);
      // state.presets.delivery.tc_methods = tc_methods;
    },
    changeDeliveryPresets__tc_list(state, tc_list) {
      Vue.set(state.presets.delivery, "tc_list", tc_list);
      // state.presets.delivery.tc_list = tc_list;
    },
    changeDeliveryPresets__addresses(state, addresses) {
      Vue.set(state.presets.delivery, "addresses", addresses);
      // state.presets.delivery.addresses = addresses;
    },

    changeDelivery(state, delivery) {
      for (let key in delivery) {
        Vue.set(state.summary.delivery, key, delivery[key]);
        // state.summary.delivery[key]=delivery[key];
      }
    },
    changeDelivery__tc_city(state, tc_city) {
      Vue.set(state.summary.delivery, "delivery_tc_city", tc_city);
      // state.summary.delivery.delivery_tc_city = tc_city;
    },
    changeDelivery__tc(state, tc) {
      Vue.set(state.summary.delivery, "delivery_tc", tc);
      // state.summary.delivery.delivery_tc = tc;
    },
    changeDelivery__method(state, method) {
      Vue.set(state.summary.delivery, "delivery_method", method);
      // state.summary.delivery.delivery_method = method;
    },

    changeDelivery__delivery_type(state, delivery_type) {
      console.log("setting delivery");
      Vue.set(state.summary.delivery, "delivery_type", delivery_type);
      // state.summary.delivery.delivery_type = delivery_type;
    },

    changeDelivery__address_id(state, address_id) {
      Vue.set(state.summary.delivery, "delivery_address_id", address_id);
      // state.summary.delivery.delivery_address_id = address_id;
    },

    changeDelivery__address(state) {
      state.summary.address = {};
      if (state && state.summary.delivery) {
        if (state.presets && state.presets.addresses && state.summary.delivery && ((state.summary.delivery.delivery_method == "tc" && state.summary.delivery.delivery_tc_method == "door") || state.summary.delivery.delivery_method == "courier")) {
          if (state.presets && state.presets.addresses && state.summary.delivery && state.summary.delivery && state.summary.delivery.delivery_address_id) {
            Vue.set(
              state.summary,
              "address",
              state.presets.addresses.find((address) => address.id == state.summary.delivery.delivery_address_id)
            );
          }
        } else {
          if (state.summary.delivery && state.summary.delivery.delivery_tc_city) {
            Vue.set(state.summary, "address", {
              address: state.summary.delivery.delivery_tc_city,
            });
          }
        }
      }
    },
  },
  actions: {
    //COMMON DATA
    changeFillial: ({ commit }, { fillial }) => commit("changeFillial", fillial),

    changePartnerId: ({ commit }, { partner_id }) => {
      console.log("partner id commit");
      commit("changePartnerId", partner_id);
    },
    changeContragentId: ({ commit }, { contragent_id }) => {
      commit("changeContragentId", contragent_id);
    },
    changeContragents: ({ commit }, { contragents }) => {
      commit("changeContragents", contragents);
    },
    changePartners: ({ commit }, { partners }) => {
      commit("changePartners", partners);
    },

    //PRESETS
    changeDeliveryPresets: ({ commit }, { presets }) => {
      commit("changeDeliveryPresets", presets);
      commit("changeDelivery__address");
    },

    changeDeliveryPresets__types: ({ commit }, { types }) => {
      commit("changeDeliveryPresets__types", types);
    },

    changeDeliveryPresets__methods: ({ commit }, { methods }) => {
      commit("changeDeliveryPresets__methods", methods);
    },
    changeDeliveryPresets__tc_methods: ({ commit }, { tc_methods }) => {
      commit("changeDeliveryPresets__tc_methods", tc_methods);
    },
    changeDeliveryPresets__tc_list: ({ commit }, { tc_list }) => {
      commit("changeDeliveryPresets__tc_list", tc_list);
    },
    changeDeliveryPresets__addresses: ({ commit }, { addresses }) => {
      commit("changeDeliveryPresets__addresses", addresses);
    },

    //SUMMARY
    changeDelivery: ({ commit }, { delivery }) => {
      commit("changeDelivery", delivery);
      commit("changeDelivery__address");
    },
    changeDelivery__tc_city: ({ commit }, { tc_city }) => {
      commit("changeDelivery__tc_city", tc_city);
    },
    changeDelivery__tc: ({ commit }, { tc }) => {
      commit("changeDelivery__tc", tc);
    },
    changeDelivery__tc_method: ({ commit }, { tc_method }) => {
      commit("changeDelivery__tc_method", tc_method);
    },
    changeDelivery__delivery_type: ({ commit }, { delivery_type }) => {
      commit("changeDelivery__delivery_type", delivery_type);
    },
    changeDelivery__delivery_method: ({ commit }, { delivery_method }) => {
      commit("changeDelivery__delivery_method", delivery_method);
    },
    changeDelivery__address_id: ({ commit }, { address_id }) => {
      commit("changeDelivery__address_id", address_id);
    },
  },
  getters: {
    summary: (state) => {
      return state.summary;
    },
    presets: (state) => {
      return state.presets;
    },
    delivery_tc_title: (state) => {
      return state.presets && state.presets.delivery && state.presets.delivery.tc_list && state.summary && state.summary.delivery && state.summary.delivery.delivery_tc ? state.presets.delivery.tc_list[state.summary.delivery.delivery_tc] : "";
    },
    delivery_tc_method_title: (state) => {
      return state.presets && state.presets.delivery && state.presets.delivery.tc_methods && state.summary && state.summary.delivery && state.summary.delivery.delivery_tc_method ? state.presets.delivery.tc_methods[state.summary.delivery.delivery_tc_method] : "";
    },
    contragent_id: (state) => {
      return state.summary && state.summary.contragent_id ? state.summary.contragent_id : "";
    },
    contragent: (state) => {
      return state.presets && state.presets.contragents && state.summary && state.summary.contragent_id ? state.presets.contragents[state.summary.contragent_id] : "";
    },
    partner_id: (state) => {
      return state.summary && state.summary.partner_id ? state.summary.partner_id : "";
    },
    partner: (state) => {
      return state.presets && state.presets.partners && state.presets.partners.length && state.summary && state.summary.partner_id ? state.presets.partners.find((partner) => partner.id == state.summary.partner_id) : "";
    },
    partners: (state) => {
      return state.presets && state.presets.partners ? state.presets.partners : "";
    },
    contragents: (state) => {
      return state.presets && state.presets.contragents ? state.presets.contragents : "";
    },
    delivery: (state) => {
      return state.summary && state.summary.delivery ? state.summary.delivery : "";
    },
    delivery_presets: (state) => {
      return state.presets && state.presets.delivery ? state.presets.delivery : "";
    },
    delivery_settings: (state, getters) => {
      return {
        delivery: getters["delivery"],
        address: getters["address"],
        fillial: getters["fillial"],
      };
    },

    fillial: (state) => {
      return state.summary && state.summary.fillial ? state.summary.fillial : "";
    },
  },
};
```

**In the template the
{{ presets }}
{{ settings}}**

returns `{ "types": {}, "methods": {}, "tc_methods": {}, "tc_list": {}, "addresses": [] } { "delivery": { "delivery_type": "", "delivery_method": "", "delivery_tc": "", "delivery_tc_method": "", "delivery_tc_city": "", "delivery_address_id": "" }, "fillial": { "address": "" } }`

like initial  in store

When i use getter in console **appData.getters["basket/delivery_settings"]**
it return the valid real time object

Also settimeouts like that

```
 mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.presets);
      console.log(this.settings);
    }, 10000);
  },
```

returns the valid object too.

Whats is my mistake?Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setters` of `computed` are returning. Instead, they should be committing.

Think of `getter` + `setter` computed as a collection of `read` (getter) and `write` (setter) functions.

Let's take one of the `computed` apart:

```js
contragent_id: {
  get() {
    return appData.getters["basket/contragent_id"];
  },
  set(value) {
    return value;
  },
}
```

Let's consider a read operation:

```js
const myValue = this.contragent_id
```

if the code would be able to describe what it does, it would be saying something like:

> *I read the value from `appData.getters["basket/contragent_id"]` (which returns the value of `appData.state.summary.contragent_id`) and store it in a constant named `myValue`*.

Great! That's exactly what it should be doing. Now let's consider a write operation (a setter):

```js
console.log(this.contragent_id) // Expect: ''; Receive: ''
this.contragent_id = '42'
console.log(this.contragent_id) // Expect: '42'. Receive: ''
```

the current code (`return value`) would be described by:

> *Here's "42"! I'm giving it back to you, I'm not doing anything with it.*

It should be described by:

> *I write `'42'` into `state.summary.contragent_id`, by committing this value to the `'basket/changeContragentId'` mutation.*

, which would look like:

```js
set(value) {
  appData.commit('basket/changeContragentId', value)
}
```

Once the mutation is performed, because of it, the getter immediately updates and starts returning the current value of `state.summary.contragent_id`, via `getters['basket/contragent_id']`, which is now `42` (or whatever we assigned).

In other words, with the committing setter, the above code will produce:

```js
console.log(this.contragent_id) // Expect: ''; Receive: ''
this.contragent_id = '42'
console.log(this.contragent_id) // Expect: '42'; Receive: '42'
```

So the local computed `contragent_id` can now be read from and written to. In fact, we'd be interacting with `state.summary.contragent_id`, via `getters` and `mutations`.

---

On a separate note, we shouldn't be using `Vue.set()` everywhere in our mutations.

We probably want to write the above mutation as:

```
changeContragentId(state, contragent_id) {
  state.summary = { ...state.summary, contragent_id };
}
```

Why?

```js
{ ...state.summary, contragent_id }
```

is shorthand for:

```js
{ ...state.summary, contragent_id: contragent_id }
```

, which creates a fresh object from `state.summary` containing everything that `state.summary` contained, plus the passed argument `contragent_id`'s value, assigned to the `contragent_id` property of this new object, regardless of whether or not the old `state.summary` had such a property or any value in it. By assignment, `state.summary`'s value is replaced with this new object. This replacement is what notifies the getters which, in turn, update all components using them (or reading directly from state).
This is the key: replacing the root prop of the state.

If we would have used

```js
state.summary.contragent_id = value
```

`state.summary` object wouldn't have been replaced, and the change would not be visible in `<template>`.
In some cases (when something else is changed at the same time), we might see  changes made to deep properties, giving a wrong impression about how Vue works.

---

I see a lot of repetition in both mutations and getters. It's unnecessary.

For example, we could replace all `state.summary` related mutations with a single one:

```js
mutations: {
  updateSummary(state, update) {
    state.summary = { ...state.summary, ...update }
  }
}
```

and now we could replace all `state.summary` related setters in components `computed` with calls to this mutation. Example:

```js
computed: {
  contragent_id: {
    get() { return appData.getters['basket/contragent_id'] },
    set(contragent_id) {
      appData.commit('basket/updateSummary', { contragent_id })
    }
  },
  partner_id: {
    get() { return appData.getters['basket/partner_id'] },
    set(partner_id) {
      appData.commit('basket/updateSummary', { partner_id })
    }
  },
  delivery: {
    get() { return appData.getters['basket/delivery'] },
    set(delivery) {
      appData.commit('basket/updateSummary', { delivery })
    }
  },
  fillial: (state) => {
    get() { return appData.getters['basket/fillial'] },
    set(fillial) {
      appData.commit('basket/updateSummary', { fillial })
    }
  }
}
```

, which could be written as:

```js
computed: {
  ...Object.assign(
    {},
    ...["contragent_id", "partner_id", "delivery", "fillial"].map((key) => ({
      [key]: {
        get() {
          return appData.getters[`basket/${key}`];
        },
        set(value) {
          appData.commit("basket/updateSummary", { [key]: value });
        },
      },
    }))
  ),
};
```

This looks complicated, doesn't it?
It's useful, we could re-use it in any component where we want to get or set `state.summary` props and all we'd have to do is specify a different array of keys, depending on what we want to expose.

So let's write a function, taking in the array of keys and place it in some `storeHelpers.js` file:

```js
import { appData } from './path/to/appData'

export const mapSummary = (keys) =>
  Object.assign(
    {},
    ...keys.map((key) => ({
      [key]: {
        get() {
          return appData.getters[`basket/${key}`];
        },
        set(value) {
          appData.commit("basket/updateSummary", { [key]: value });
        },
      },
    }))
  );
```

Now we can

```js
import { mapSummary } from './path/to/storeHelpers'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapSummary(["contragent_id", "partner_id", "delivery", "fillial"])
  }
}
```

Similarly, you could do this for any object you want to update inside the state, so you wouldn't have to write a mutation for each of its properties. In your case, you probably want to have `updatePresets` and `updatePresetsDelivery` mutation functions and `mapPresets` & `mapPresetsDelivery` helpers, because both `state.presets` and `state.presets.delivery` are objects.

If your state has ***a lot*** of objects inside other objects, rather than writing one mutation and one mapper function for each individual object (which is still an improvement over writing a `mutation` for each individual object property), you might consider a single `updateBasket` mutation and one `mapBasket` helper which would also take the object's `path` as a parameter. Now, that mutation, having a dynamic path, would be a good use case for `Vue.set()`.

Keep in mind nesting objects inside other objects inside a state is generally a sign of poor architecture. In your specific case, I'd probably go for three separate stores: one called `basketSummary`, one called `basketPresets` and one called `basketPresetsDelivery` (or `basketDelivery`).

Alternatively, you could go for nested stores, which would be be `basket/summary`, `basket/presets` and `basket/presets/delivery`, since you're using namespacing. Namespacing was actually developed to address cases like yours.

This subject is debatable (a lot of developers have strong opinions about store architecture) but, from my experience, having many smaller stores, each controlling a flat structure (a level: the properties of only one object) is generally preferable to having one big store, with lots of getters, actions and mutations, each having multiple levels of object spreading (or having to use `Vue.set()`).
It simplifies testing and debugging.
Ultimately, it allows more granular/precise control over complex data structures, considerably reducing the time spent developing (and debugging).

---

Readability in getters could also be improved:

```js
getters: {
  contragent_id: (state) => {
    return state.summary && state.summary.contragent_id
      ? state.summary.contragent_id
      : "";
  }
}
```

could be written as:

```js
getters: {
  contragent_id: (state) => state.summary?.contragent_id || ""
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your great work and great response. I will now try to implement the advice you gave me. The reason I wrote these setters is because I don't use them, I only use a dispatcher to set values within a component and a get to get them. However, this may have led to some kind of error that I simply did not notice.

Comment: If you don't need setters, you should simplify your computed (by default they're getter only): `computed: { ...mapGetters('basket', ['contragent_id', 'partner_id']) }`. This creates `this.contragent_id` and `this.partner_id` on your component in sync with the store getters. They're read only, you can't assign to them. Computed setters are for when you want to assign (e.g: use with `v-model`). If you need more help you might want to [export](https://codesandbox.io/docs/importing#import-local-projects-via-cli) your project to codesandbox and be more precise about what's not working exactly.